# Android борьба за главный поток между progressbar и сложной операцией

Tags: android, progress-bar

Всем привет, у меня возникла проблема. У меня в главном потоке выполняется достаточно сложавя операция(открытие и расшифровка файла, парсинг этого файла). Все это дело занимает около 3 секунд. Я решил, почему бы не оповестить пользователя (идет открытие, показать progressbar). Раньше сложные операции я выполнял в отдельном потоке и по старту показывал progressbar, а в конце убирал при помощи handler'a. А сейчас я решил показать progressbar сразу перед запуском сложной операции (строкой выше). И вот странно,несмотря на то, что поток, казалось бы, один, но сначала выпoлняется сложная операция и только потом отображается мой progressbar, из-за чего это происходит?

Comment: Проблема в том, что операции отрисовки выполняются через очередь, а она проверяется когда UI-поток свободен - у Вас же он освобождается когда задача выполнена.

Comment: @woesss так я говорю UI потоку: отрисуй мне progressbar и только потом запускаю выполнение задачи, почему же в данном случае UI поток занят?

Comment: @woesss если я правильно понимаю, то команды же должны выполняться последовательно в одном потоке, так почему тогда приоритет отдается последующей задаче, странно это.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Главный поток — это то, что иногда называют потоком пользовательского интерфейса.
потому что progress bar имеет анимацию, она выполняется обновлением пользовательского интерфейса, если в промежутке залетит тяжелая задача, то progress bar остановиться, как и все графические действия, пока эта задача не завершиться. 
Когда приложение выполняет интенсивную работу в ответ на действия пользователя, эта одиночная модель потока может показывать плохую производительность, если приложение реализовано неправильно. То есть, если все происходит в потоке пользовательского интерфейса как у вас, выполнение долговременных операций, таких как сетевой доступ,запросы к базе данных, работа с файлами системы, парсинг файлов, то будет блокировать весь пользовательский интерфейс. Когда поток заблокирован, не могут обрабатываться никакие события, включая события изменения отображения (progress bar). С точки зрения пользователя приложение выглядит зависшим. Хуже того, если поток пользовательского интерфейса заблокирован более нескольких секунд (в настоящее время около 5 секунд), отображается печально известное диалоговое окно «приложение не отвечает» ANR. После этого недовольный пользователь может выйти из вашего приложения и удалить его. Выполняйте тяжелые операции в отдельном потоке. А уведомлять пользователя о том что сейчас идет процесс, это очень хорошая практика. Делайте это в главном потоке-) Удачи.